# Comparing arrays to produce a key array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have a problem that I'm sure is easy to solve with PHP's inbuilt functions or with one or two lines of code, but I cant seem to find a solution using my limited experince.

I have a master array:

```
$master_array = ('location_1','location_2','location_3','location_4','location_5');
```

I get given an array:

```
$submitted_array = ('location_1','location_3');
```

And I need to compare both arrays to form an array such as this:

```
$locations = (0,2);
```

Where the numbers in the $locations array are the locations of the $submitted_array elements in the $master_array.

There must be a way of doing this without loops, surely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = array_keys(array_intersect($master_array , $submitted_array));
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$locations = array_keys(array_intersect($master_array, $submitted_array));
```